# Getting Index of ArrayList of Array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, jtextfield

I made an ArrayList of arrays of JTextField.
Now I want to get the value of the first position of the array that was previously stored in the ArrayList.

```
ArrayList <JTextField []> text_field;
text_field = new ArrayList <JTextField []> ();
```

I have tried doing this:

```
text_field.get (row)[column];
```

But this didn't work. How should I change it?

And how can I add the JTextField onto the panel?

```
for (int i = 0; i < text_field.size (); i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {

  }
}
```

Comment: What are the types of `row` and `column`?

Comment: row and column are just index numbers

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Do you get a runtime exception or compiler error? If so, please post it. (Remember to tag me in your reply).

Comment: I am really confused why people will use the conveience of Lists and then also use Array - why not `ArrayList<ArrayList<JTtextFiled>>`

Comment: The second part of your question - how to add components to the JPannel, was discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13907202/adding-components-into-jpanel-inside-a-jframe). [This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html#add) is from official Java Tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```java
((JTextField[]) text_field.get(row))[column];
```

Comment: Well on my JVM both statements compile and run without errors. I've actually answered this question before checking your statement. So this is a mystery to me. What Java version / platform are you on? And what type of error were you getting?